# My PHP row array is giving me duplicates in my table, and I don't know why

Tags: php, for-loop, key-pair

Everyone.

I'm trying to do a join on three tables.  Here's the code that gets that done:

```
$query = "SELECT Distinct ID, Date, SC_LName, SC_FName, Activity_Type, Hours, Pay_Rate, PT_First_Name, PT_Last_Name
FROM Payroll
LEFT OUTER JOIN Plans ON Plans.Client_ID = Payroll.Client_ID
GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE( DATE,  '%m/%d/%Y' ), Payroll.SC_LName";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

After the query, I have a for loop within a while loop, which looks like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $daterange = $row['Approval_Date'];
    $m30 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 30 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m60 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 60 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m90 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 90 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m120 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 120 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m150 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 150 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m180 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 190 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m210 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 210 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m240 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 240 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m270 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 270 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m300 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 300 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m330 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 330 days', strtotime($daterange)));
    $m360 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('+ 360 days', strtotime($daterange)));

    $Hourly_Pay = round($row['Pay_Rate'] * $row['Hours'],2);
    asort($row);
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        $time = strtotime($val);
        $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
        $myformat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['Date']));
            if ( $time > strtotime("01/28/2015") 
              AND $time < strtotime("03/31/2015") 
              AND $key <> "Date" 
              AND $myformat = $newformat) {
                 echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Date'];  
                 echo "</td><td>"; 
                 if (strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m30)) {
                        echo "30 Day";
                 }; 
                 if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m60) 
                    AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m90)) {
                        echo "60 Day";
                 }; 
                 if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m90) 
                    AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m120)) {
                       echo "90-Day";
                 }; 
                 if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m120) 
                    AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m150)) {
                       echo "210 Day";
                 }; 
                 if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m150) 
                    AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m180)) {
                       echo "150-Day";
                 }; 
                 if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m180) 
                    AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m210)) {
                       echo "180-Day";
                 }; 
                 if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m210) 
                     AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m240)) {
                       echo "210 Day";
                 }; 
                 echo "</td><td>"  . $row['SC_LName'] . "</td><td>" 
                    . $row['SC_FName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Title'] 
                    . "</td><td>" . $row['PT_Last_Name'] . "</td><td>" 
                    . $row['PT_First_Name'] . "</td><td>" 
                    . $row['Activity_Type'] . "</td><td>" 
                    . $row['Hours'] . "</td><td>" 
                    . $row['Pay_Rate'] . "</td><td>" 
                    . $Hourly_Pay .  "</td><td>" 
                    . $row['Budget_Amt'] . "</td><td>" 
                    . $row['Notes'] . "</td></tr>";
              }
      }
}
```

My problem is that I'm getting duplicate rows.  Rows are coming up with exactly the same data.  This isn't the expected behavior.  The expected behavior is that there's something different about each row.  Either the PT_LName/FName should be different, the date should be different, or the Activity_Type should be different.  They shouldn't all be the same for any two rows, but I'm getting duplicates of each.  And the number of duplicates seems to vary.

This is the first time I'm posting here, so if you need any additional information, please let me know.  I'm new to this. :)

Edited to add:  I found the solution, based on generous help I got here. :)

I changed my query to this:

```
$query = "SELECT * from Plans
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payroll ON Payroll.Client_ID = Plans.Client_ID";
```

and I changed my IF statement to this:

```
if ( $time > strtotime("01/28/2015") AND $time < strtotime("03/31/2015") AND $key == "Date" AND $myformat = $newformat) {echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Date'];  echo "</td><td>"; if (strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m30)) {echo "30 Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m60) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m90)) {echo "60 Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m90) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m120)) {echo "90-Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m120) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m150)) {echo "210 Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m150) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m180)) {echo "150-Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m180) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m210)) {echo "180-Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m210) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m240)) {echo "210 Day";}; echo "</td><td>"  . $row['SC_LName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['SC_FName'] .  "</td><td>" . $row['PT_Last_Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['PT_First_Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Activity_Type'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Hours'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Pay_Rate'] . "</td><td>" . $Hourly_Pay .  "</td><td>" . $row['Budget_Amt'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Notes'] . "</td></tr>";
```

Taken together, those two changes gave me the right amount of rows.  I was doing something wrong with the key/Date pairing, and making the join too complicated.

Comment: Are you sure that all the dates are the same ? You might be losing some time precision on hours / minutes / seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Clement. :)  The Date field is limited to the day, so I don't think hours, minutes, or seconds could be causing duplication.

Comment: First of all, make sure that this is not a problem of your database query already.

Comment: CBroe:  I ran the query in phpmyadmin, and I'm getting reasonable results.   No duplication there.

Comment: Hard to say, but I suggest you make up a new test page and reduce your PHP to one or two conditional statements. The cause is obviously in there and not the query itself. Once you've determined what's causing that, then you can slowly start adding in the other conditional statements. I'd try and take the `foreach` outside the `while` loop and see what that does. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Fred.  I'll try that.  That sounds like a good place to start. :)

Comment: You're welcome Brian.

Comment: FYI: You can post your own answer too; Stack lets you do that. I think this is a good question and deemed worthy of Stack's questions/answers archive, *cheers*. Oh, and you can accept your own answer also, once Stack time limit lets you. Glad you found your solution.

Comment: Thanks, Fred.  I'll provide my own answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the reason you are seeing what you perceive as duplicate rows is because you include ID and PT_Last_Name in the SELECT clause but never use it in the output.

You might want to drop by https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask for some advice on structuring your code better.

Comment: Thanks.  :)  I actually rewrote the query and some of the code.  I think it works now.  I need to update this or close it or something.  I'll post the solution, though, for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, based on generous help I got here. :)

I changed my query to this:

```
$query = "SELECT * from Plans
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payroll ON Payroll.Client_ID = Plans.Client_ID";
```

and I changed my IF statement to this:

```
if ( $time > strtotime("01/28/2015") AND $time < strtotime("03/31/2015") AND $key == "Date" AND $myformat = $newformat) {echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Date'];  echo "</td><td>"; if (strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m30)) {echo "30 Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m60) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m90)) {echo "60 Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m90) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m120)) {echo "90-Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m120) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m150)) {echo "210 Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m150) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m180)) {echo "150-Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m180) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m210)) {echo "180-Day";}; if (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime($m210) AND strtotime($row['Date']) < strtotime($m240)) {echo "210 Day";}; echo "</td><td>"  . $row['SC_LName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['SC_FName'] .  "</td><td>" . $row['PT_Last_Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['PT_First_Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Activity_Type'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Hours'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Pay_Rate'] . "</td><td>" . $Hourly_Pay .  "</td><td>" . $row['Budget_Amt'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Notes'] . "</td></tr>";
```

Taken together, those two changes gave me the right amount of rows. I was doing something wrong with the key/Date pairing, and making the join too complicated.